# Having the inequality $e^{2x}+ me^{x} + m - 1 >0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, what's the value of $m$?

Tags: inequality

I've done the substitution $e^x = y$ with $y > 0$ resulting in the inequality $y^2 + my + m - 1 > 0$. How I know this problem is solved , knowing $a = 1 > 0 $ is taking $\delta < 0$ but that leads me to $m = 2$ ( where the function is $0$ ) for rest of $m$s the inequality is always $> 0$ , but on the answers it says that only $m\geq 1$  is the correct solution. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. We have to find for which $m\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that 
$$y^2+my+m−1=(y+1)(y+m-1)>0$$
 for all $y=e^x>0$.

Comment: yeah I get what you've done , but why my answer is not correct ? Indeed , in the way you've done it I get m>= 1 , witch is the correct answer

Comment: Actually I have not fully understood the second part of your answer. Anyway, after the substitution, the factorization of the quadratic polynomial yields easily  the answer.

Comment: How I've been told to do this tipe of inequality , is I get the delta of the function based of m , for example here I have m^2 -4(m+1) and than consider this < 0 ... and solve the problem from there with another delta

Comment: The $\delta$ approach gives you a stronger condition such that $y^2+my+m−1>0$ for ALL $y$ (and not just for $y>0$). Is it clear now?

Comment: Ah I get it , thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $$e^{2x}=(e^x)^2$$ we can substitute $$e^x=t$$ and you have
$$t^2+mt+m-1>0$$
to solve.
And completing the square
$$\left(t+\frac{m}{2}\right)^2+m-1-\frac{m^2}{4}>0$$
Now you have to distinguish several cases:
1)$$m-1-\frac{m^2}{4}\geq 0$$ we have
$$m^2-4m+4\le 0$$ so $$(m-2)^2\le 0$$ and we get $$m=2$$

Comment: That's exactly what the OP did...

Comment: yeah and that's not correct apparently

Comment: And why should it be not correct?

Comment: becouse the answer says it needs to be only m>= 1

Comment: And $$m=2\geq 1$$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Using the substitution $u=\mathrm e^x$, we obtain the quadratic polynomial
$$p(u)=u^2+mu+m-1,\quad\text{in which }u>0.$$
So we have to determine the values of $m$ such that $p(u)>0$ for all $u>0$.

Observe the discriminant of this polynomial is
$$\Delta=m^2-4(m-1)=(m-2)^2,$$
so it has two real roots, and we know $p(u)>0$ outside the interval of the roots. This comprises $(0,+\infty)$ if and only if both roots are non-positive. This amounts, denoting their sum and product by $s$ and $p$ respectively, that we have both
$$s\le 0, \quad p\le 0. $$
Can you end the calculations?